# Orphan Bounties

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, moderator-tools, tag-wiki

Should question with sufficient information and problem description be reviewed and commented  at-least by moderator holding badge for <kbd>tag</kbd> (e.g <kbd>python</kbd>) before bounty finishes without any answer?

Moderator (being superior and holding cap) should at-least get a notification about which bounties are about to expire without any answer.

This will certainly help unanswered count fall down to some number (at-least some of them will be closed).

OP will also will not feel like posting Orphan question :-( (Waste of reputation without receiving enough attention where bounty was already open for the reason "Not Received enough attention").

Bounty opened with reason  "Not Received enough attention" and still being Orphan (without any answer and views) should be flagged for moderator attention (Please answer if you have or at-least leave a comment holding responsibility of keeping community happy and wealthy)

### Moderator Here:

A person holding cap for the relevant badge. If you are awarded with badge means you are superior with good amount of understanding of technology

It certainly does not make sense when you open a bounty for a question with "Not received enough attention" and still did not get a single comment or answer

Comment: *"Bounty opened with reason "Not Received enough attention" and still being Orphan (without any answer and views) should be flagged for moderator attention"* What would you expect a moderator to do?

Comment: The moderators are here to keep the site running smoothly. They're not here to heroically defeat evil unanswered questions with their +50 Swords of Answering.

Comment: @Pilot I downvoted- downvotes indicate disagreement on meta. I disagree with your proposition.

Comment: Just because one is a moderator doesn't mean they are programming ninjas of all disciples. Anyway, some questions with a bounty just don't have enough information to answer them, no matter how much reputation you put in.

Comment: @Pilot It's about **views**, not answers or comments. You can't guarantee a bounty will produce any answers or comments, but more people will definitely look at the bountied question.

Comment: @BlueIce define cost of **definitely**

Comment: @JasonC does it make sense to you opening a bounty with `x` reputations and **"Not received enough attention"** with complete problem description and logs and still no activity on question ? no view count no answer no comment ..How discouraging it is My dear friend

Comment: @Pilot Yes, it makes sense. Maybe nobody knows the answer. Maybe the question was worded poorly and it is unclear what you are asking. Maybe nobody *wanted* to answer, simply because nobody felt like it. You are not entitled to receive answers to questions here.

Comment: @JasonC I believe in your comment.But there could be some question with enough problem description and logs and which actually makes sense. What should be done for such question

Comment: @Pilot By the way, assuming you are talking about the question I think you are talking about, you added a bounty less than 24 hours ago. There is still 5 days left on the bounty. Be patient. You don't get to complain that nobody volunteered their own free time on a weekend to drop what they were doing and help you with your "urgent" question.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for monitoring my activity.but I am not only talking about my question.Please ..please

Comment: @Pilot You still can't make anyone answer. If you *need* somebody to answer now, then find a paid site.

Answer (score 6):

No, moderators shouldn't have to look at ending bounties.

This is for two reasons- firstly, **bounties are the price you pay for getting more views for a question.** This means that more people will look at it, not that an answer will have to be given.

This brings me to the next point:
**Nobody has to answer a question**. The question may be awful, but it may have a bounty on it. Does this mean that there should be an answer or more views for this bad question? Probably not.

The community does a pretty good job of telling people when they have poor questions- we don't really need moderator involvement to decide that. And for good bounties, nobody answers the questions that are attached because nobody knows the answer. People don't just pass up huge amounts of rep for fun, you know :)

Comment: @Pilot But it doesn't mean you are obligated to answer a question.

Comment: @Pilot It doesn't even mean you are obligated to *read* every question. The people here are here on their own free time, helping to answer questions when (and only when) they feel like it. Plus, it might not even be an answerable or appropriate question to begin with.

Comment: @Pilot Also, don't you think that a user that is already invested in a tag like that would have seen the featured question?

Answer (score 3):

Pilot, you are confusing moderators and answerers.

Moderators are volunteers that help make sure the community runs smoothly.  They, in fact, have the least time of anyone to respond to questions as they have lots of administrative duties like keeping review queues in check and dealing with any user issues that come up.

A bounty already makes it so that a question ends up in the featured list for a week and if it doesn't get an answer, it is probably because it is a bad question, either because it is not clear enough what is being asked, because it is is not researched enough or because it is too localized to be of general use.

If a question isn't getting enough attention even with a bounty, the best way to get an answer is fix the question.  It isn't the role or job of moderators (who are not paid) to make sure you get an answer and often they aren't even the most qualified people to answer.

Comment: While I would agree with what you've said; a bounty can also go unanswered because it is about something that few people have sufficient knowledge in to answer; e.g. a library with a small user base. As opposed to being a bad question

Comment: @Richardtingle yes, though if it has such a small user base that it gets no attention then it is also probably fairly unlikely that either a moderator can help or that the answer will be useful to a significant population. This is why I mentioned the too localized bit even if it isn't quite bad enough to make it a truly bad question. There are still exceptions but the narrower the audience the less overall usefulness there is.

Comment: I would say that is why too localised was removed as a closure reason; that sort of use. Just because its about an unusual technology doesn't make it a bad/not useful question. Obviously the whole feature request isn't great but its catorgarising questions with a small user base as "bad" that I object to

Comment: @RichardTingle - yes, I agree that that is why Too Localized was removed since it isn't a "bad" question.  Often, they can still be improved though by trying to generalize more or by providing more of the information necessary for someone unfamiliar with the obscure system to be able to answer.  Perhaps improvements in tagging to make it easier for someone to find who might know the answer.  And if it really is so localized that nobody else is having the problem, then it may not be close worthy, but it still isn't particularly helpful, so I would argue, while not "bad", it really isn't "good".